# MySql stopped Working after npm audit fix --force

Tags: mysql, sql, npm

I have tried many solutions already. Even completely removed and reinstalled but the same error comes up.

> ```
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
> ```

See the code (13) its different form (2) for missing socket file.
the `mysqld.sock` and other files  in that mysqld folder do exist. 
I tried changing the port number, didn't work.
I tried connection with tcp, didn't work.
I also tried many solutions involving ownership & and permissions.
Now tried to connect via Js script & MySql work bench. It works via Js & MySql workbench, but gives the same error on terminal. 
How to fix it?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: now i tried, mysql works via js script and mysql workbench ; but only gives the above error while accessing  via ubuntu terminal.

Comment: I've removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag since you don't seem to be using that product.